# Personal Vue 3 component package missing template or render function

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I recently uploaded my own Vue 3 component to NPM to make it usable for others. When using it in other projects it gives this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
at <VueToggle id="1" title="Toggle me" > 
at <App>
```

What could be the reason this is happening? The way I am building and publishing the app is by running this code.

```
import VueToggle from "./components/VueToggle";

export default {
    install(app) {
        app.component("vue-toggle", VueToggle);
    }
};
```

And then running this build command in my package.json:

```
"build-library": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name vue-toggle-component ./src/install.js",
```

How I use my component in a different project:

```
<template>
  <VueToggle id="1" title="Toggle me"/>
</template>

<script>
import VueToggle from 'vue-toggle-component';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    VueToggle,
  }
}
</script>
```

The component itself:

```
<template>
  <section class="wrapper" :class="{dark: darkTheme}" :title="title">
    <input
      :id="id"
      :name="name"
      v-model="toggleState"
      class="toggle"
      type="checkbox"
      @click="toggleState = !toggleState"
    />
    <label :for="id" class="toggler" :style="[toggleState && {'background': activeColor}]"/>
    <span class="title" v-text="title" @click="toggleState = !toggleState"/>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VueToggle',
  props: {
    activeColor: {type: String, default: '#9FD6AE'},
    darkTheme: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: [String, Boolean], default: false},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    toggled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      toggleState: this.toggled
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toggle-component

Comment: This error is quite obvious. user render function with jsx or <template></template> in VueToggle

Comment: @AhmadKZX The component itself: https://github.com/niels-bosman/vue-toggle-component/blob/main/src/components/VueToggle.vue (should not be anything wrong with). And the usage is how it should be.

Comment: @NielsBosman I can't reproduce the issue. Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 3):

The following concerns a new project using Vue 3 & Typescript created with Quasar CLI (v2 beta). Although I'm getting the same error reported by the OP, my source layout might be different as I'm not using single-file components.

> [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.

I resolved the above issue by specifying the `vue` file as the component source. I typically split my components into separate `vue` and `ts` files.

The related fragment:

```
MyComponent: require("./components/My.vue").default
```

In context:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MyComponent: require("./components/My.vue").default
  },
  setup() {
  ...
```

To quiet the linters, I have the following `es-lint` comments

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment, @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access, @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    MyComponent: require("./components/My.vue").default
  },
```

Ideally, the `import` statement would be used instead of the inline `require` assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to  import `'vue-toggle-component'` like a Vue component, when your library is exporting a Vue plugin (made up of an `install` function that declares your component).

There are two way to fix this.

### Solution 1

Remove the component import entirely.

```
// component.vue (separate project)
<template>
  <VueToggle id="1" title="Toggle me"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Then import your library plugin and styles in `index.js` of the separate project. You should activate the plugin using `Vue.use()`.

```
// index.js (separate project)
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from './App.vue';

import VueToggleComponent from 'vue-toggle-component';
import '@vue-toggle-component/dist/style.css';

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');

app.use(VueToggleComponent);
```

Your component should now be imported by default into the project and can be used from anywhere.

### Solution 2

Add anonymized exports for each component for individual importing.

```
// install.js
import VueToggle from "./components/VueToggle";

export default {
    install(app) {
        app.component("vue-toggle", VueToggle);
    }
};

export { default as VueToggle } from "./components/VueToggle";
```

Then import the component as a non-default export in your separate project.

```
// component.vue (separate project)
<template>
  <VueToggle id="1" title="Toggle me"/>
</template>

<script>
import { VueToggle } from 'vue-toggle-component';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    VueToggle,
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally, install your library's styles.

```
// index.js (separate project)
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from './App.vue';

import '@vue-toggle-component/dist/style.css';

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```

#### Conclusion

Personally, I think Solution #2 is more flexible and intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your component, replace

```
import VueToggle from 'vue-toggle-component';
```

with

```
import VueToggle from 'vue-toggle-component.vue';
```

Or if component users use webpack, they may specify in config:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.vue', '.ts', '.js']
}
```